# How to use compiled angular 2+ project(js code) in other projects ( purl html, angular 1 or angular 2+ or other front-end frameworks)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, build, runtime

Now we have 2 projects, one project is **Common Components**, another is **Manage System**. And **Common Components** is built by Angular4, **Manage System** can be any framework.

Now we want to call Objects of the project **Common Components** in the way of running time.

- When we ran `ng build --prod`, we got such js files as follows,

  inline.812ba51cb65d5b4729c0.bundle.js,
     polyfills.805265a201496887139d.bundle.js,
     scripts.c44dd7aa4586c311cdaf.bundle.js,
     vendor.b19bafe3297743c04903.bundle.js,
     main.5c3ed0f42e8c01535b0d.bundle.js
- Include them in index.html with `<script type="text/javascript" src=“<the url of js file>”></script>`
- Add root component selector of **Common Components** libs in index.html (such as )

When the above steps is done, we can load js files, but can not work well, **Common Components** style can not display normally.

Now, we try to embed the compiled js files into template, will emit an error message as follows, the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.
[error message link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gD2N.png)

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that anyway. Use Angular6 Elements.

Comment: @ritaj, Hi many thanks for your good advice, I will try Angular6 Elements. O(∩_∩)O~